# Is it possible to login using the Spring SecurityConfiguration HttpSecurity without a password?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I know my question is weird a little bit but in an application connected to an LDAP server we need just to get the user to login into the app.

The application is a Spring AngularJS.

So now i'm changing the code to do that but i find out that the login method is done into a Spring security configuration and uses a password so i need to get the password from the Data Base (`user.getPassword()`), the issue is that the password is encrypted with the **PasswordEncoder** so there is no way to decrypte it (mentioned in an answer here in that forom) ..

anyway i wonder if there is a way to login with spring security using just the userName (without a password) ..

I tried to remove the password declaration from the configuration class but it doesn't work.

In that class called (`public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`)  i had the next config:

```
  @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        .key(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getRememberMe().getKey())
    .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
        .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
}
```

Here is the login method:

```
        function login (credentials) {
        alert("log in this");
        var data = 'j_username=' + encodeURIComponent(credentials.username) 
             +'&j_password=' + encodeURIComponent(credentials.password) +
            '&remember-me=' + credentials.rememberMe + '&submit=Login';

        return $http.post('api/authentication', data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
```

Any idea guys?

Thank youuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a `SecurityContext` at any time of your application, it doesn't matter if it has a password or not:

```
    Authentication authentication = 
  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);//set with authorities

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

With this you are actually just informed to spring that you have a `registered` user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're retrieving your user details, but maybe you could just use j_username for both the username and password, then just ignore it in the method that retrieves your user details.